# SSRS scheduling - time change issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have come upon with an issue for scheduling in SSRS.  For instance, if I was to set a start time of a schedule to be at 8:00am from the client (in DST), SSRS will save it as 7:00am of the SSRS server time (in ST). The schedule start time will be displayed from the client as 8:00am when DST applies.  Hence the schedule will start at 7:00am ST.  However, when the actual time is switched back to ST from the client, the schedule start time from the client will be displayed as 7:00am, and schedule will start at 7:00am ST.  I would like the schedule to start at 8:00am in ST, not 7:00am.  What's the best way to adjust the time difference when a time change occurs?  Thanks.

Comment: My situation is similar.   Our local reports are shortly going to be migrated to a corporate server in Arizona (no DST), while my site is in New Mexico.  Being able to adjust the schedule for DST while being hosted on a server that does not suffer from it looks like it is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is using the host servers clock for its scheduling; it doesn't care where you are, where your recipient is, or what time zone it's in - when the servers clock hits 7:00, your subscription is going to run.  The behavior you're seeking here is rather unusual.

To make it easier to manage long-term, consider creating a shared schedule object (or collection of them, if you need reports sent at other times), and having all of your subscription use the same shared object.  That way, you'll only have to manage the schedule for all of your reports in one location.

To take it a step further, you could then set up a job to update that shared schedule's time in the ReportServer database during the DST conversions, but that may begin to overcomplicate the problem.